# refactoring code from ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular after spending the last few years on react projects.

I have a component that is using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and I don't like my solution.  The trouble is that I am finding it tough to find any good real world examples of `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

For example, I have a component a bit like this:

```
  files: Uploads[] = [];

  get canUpload() {
    return this.files.length > 0l
  }

  get isUploading() {
    return this.files.length > 0 && this.files.some((f) => f.state === FileUpLoadState.uploading);
  }

  get activeFiles() {
    return this.files.filter((f) => f.state !== FileUpLoadState.success);
  }

  uploadFiles() {
    if (!this.files.length) {
      return;
    }

    const fileList: FileList = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;

    for (const uploadedFile of Array.prototype.slice.call(fileList)) {
      // do stuff
      this.files.push(new Upload(file));
    }

  }
```

I have these properties that are used in the template like this;

```
 <button (click)="uploadFiles()" [disabled]="!this.canUpload">Upload</button>
```

I really don't like this, using default change detection won't scale and when changes get propagated are outside of my control.

How can I refactor this code to use OnPush change detection?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: I'm refactoring to redux.  No idea how it is supposed to work in angular.  TBH finding angular a ghetto

Comment: _I have a component that is using changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and I don't like my solution_ what dont you like about your current implementation? As it is, its hard to understand your question. And the fact that the implementation of `uploadFiles` isnt correct makes it even worst.

Comment: All the angular documentation and dependencies are split across version 2 to version 7 or wherever the hell it is now.  No idea what goes where.  It is needlessly complex and I don't believe anyone knows how it works in any particular version

Comment: Sure, there are indeed outdated articles out there and ppl who will answer to your question without having a clear idea of what they are talking. Nevertheless, that doesnt give you an excuse to come up with a poorly written problem. I would strongly suggest you to read [this article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html), it should give you an idea of what happens behind the scenes in angular and maybe help you reformulate your question/issue.

Comment: What is poorly communicated is the whole framework.  I've done a lot of react and these problems don't exist there.  I am stunned anyone uses this framework.  It is a maze of outdated posts and dependencies.  Every project out there must be playing catch up with where they are.  All the github issues in the dependencies all say fixed next version.  God knows what version that is.  You could spend your life upgrading angular.

Comment: look at the answers below.  I am going to put my neck out and say nobody really knows how onPush works or is really doing it.  Seems like it is against the way it is supposed to work.  And zones, who on earth needs zones.  It is insanity

Comment: You are over exaggerating a lot of the mentioned points and going off topic. Anyhow, there are a lot of good resources out there that explain how to implement  a component with OnPush cd strategy. Hopefully you will take a look and come back with a concrete issue.

Comment: every angular article is about 30000 lines long because it is needlessly complex, over engineered and just not fit for purpose.  rxjs everywhere for no good reason

Comment: really wish I could delete this question.  Nobody knows the answer and I no longer care.  I'm refactoring to redux.  I know how that works without reading war and peace blog posts to find out how to do something

Comment: @dagda1 Angular has [a documentation](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) that is indeed long, but very thorough. Some well-known websites also have [timeless/versionless articles](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) to explain core concepts. You dislike Angular, and that's your right, and I agree it can be overwhelming. But when you learn how to use it, it becomes very powerful, and IMO way more than Redux !

Comment: I do find it very frustrating and much more complicated than react and not for reasons I can justify.  Not having the separation between template and class with jsx makes life so much easier.  No cryptic dsl syntax or expressions in string templates.  I am biased towards react and I'm not seeing anything to suggest this is better.  Reacft is one way dataflow by default.

Thank you for the answer, that really helps a hell of a lot

Comment: @dagda1 Then why would you use Angular ? Stick to React, you will gain much more time than if you have to learn Angular (which is loooong). And to answer you, I personally find Angular much cleaner than react for the same reasons you gave. Guess it's everyone's take ! But seriously, if you can, don't bother using Angular, your users won't see the difference. Just learn Angular on the side if you want to, but React is totally fine !

Comment: I'm in a contract that uses react.  I'm not doing it for any other reason than that,  Not really by choice but I can see some good sides now with onPush.  I still think there is some magic happening but at least a lot less

Comment: @dagda1 if you have any further question, feel free to ask them, I could maybe point you in the right direction. Otherwise, if you want to understand core concepts, [NetBasal](https://netbasal.com/), [Ng University](https://angular-university.io/), [Ng in depth](https://blog.angularindepth.com/) and some medium writers are very efficient and explain the concepts in no time !

Comment: @trichetriche thank you, I think I wrote the above comments before I discovered reactive forms and knew OnPush was possible.  Feeling a bit better about angular.  Still miss jsx and it does seem a bit needlessly complex.  But now the magic is almost gone, I feel more comfortable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People *answer* you, but they don't **explain** you.

`OnPush` strategy is the most efficient strategy when it comes to change detection. Angular doesn't implement it by default, because newcomers are used to see magic (i.e. default strategy is more error-friendly and understandable when you start using Angular).

To detect changes, Angular listens to events on your view. With the default strategy, that can result in a lot of useless change detection.

In the push strategy, you control when the change detection is triggered.

In both cases, Angular uses memory references to know when your data has been updated. That's why object immutability is so important in Angular, and also why reactive programming works so well.

That being said, if you want to switch to the push strategy, you should use the following :

```js
  // files: Uploads[] = [];
  files: BehaviorSubject<Uploads[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  add(item) {
    this.files.pipe(first()).subscribe(files => this.files.next([...files, item]));
  }

  get canUpload() {
    // return this.files.length > 0l
    return this.files.pipe(
      map(files => files.length),
      map(size => !!size)
    );
  }

  get isUploading() {
    // return this.files.length > 0 && this.files.some((f) => f.state === FileUpLoadState.uploading);
    return this.files.pipe(
      startWith(false),
      filter(files => !!files.length),
      filter(files => files.some(f => f.state === FileUpLoadState.uploading)),
      map(() => true)
    );
  }

  get activeFiles() {
    // return this.files.filter((f) => f.state !== FileUpLoadState.success);
    return this.files.pipe(
      map(files => files.filter(f => f.state !== FileUpLoadState.success)),
    );
  }

  uploadFiles() {
    /*
    if (!this.files.length) {
      return;
    }

    const fileList: FileList = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;

    for (const uploadedFile of Array.prototype.slice.call(fileList)) {
      // do stuff
      this.files.push(new Upload(file));
    }
    */
    this.files.pipe(
      filter(files => !!files.length),
      map(files => (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files),
      first()
    ).subscribe(files => {
      for (const uploadedFile of Array.prototype.slice.call(fileList)) {
        // do stuff
        this.add(new Upload(file));
      }
    });
  }
```

This is one of many implementations you can do. I'm not sure this will work the way you expect, I just "translated" the code, so you might have one or two adjustements to make.

With this, your view gets updated automatically when your collection changes. You don't have to do anything. This complies with the push strategy, because the reactive programming triggers the change detection.

And because every getter depends on your BehaviorSubject, they all get updated at every change in that subject.

Just a "drawback" (which really, isn't), is that in your component template, you have to use the async pipe :

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="canUpload | async">...</ng-container>
```

if you have questions, feel free to ask them !

Comment: I'm using rxjs 5.  There is no pipe on behaviour subject.  Can you suggest an alternative.  Also where is the the map function coming from

Comment: it seems wrong to have these subscriptions in getters.  how would you approach this problem?  subscribe once in ngoninit and update a state object?

Comment: @dagda1 you can use `mySubject.asObservable()` to get the pipe method, but it should be there by default. What version are you using ? And you don't have a single subscription in the getters, you only have observables. The subscriptions will be in your component, through the `async` pipe.

Comment: @Milad there isn't a **single** subscription that isn't closed. So I don't see where you see memory leaks. Function names are objectives, I just copied the code, I don't see why you would talk about that but sure. The code is very easy to unit test, you just find it difficult because you don't know how. The code is preety simple, it's you that probably don't understand sh*t. OnPush works on memory references **and reactive programming**, meaning that on each change on the proxy (the subject), the changes are automatically reflected into the view.

Comment: @Milad the code is **very simple** and self explanatory. There is no "inside function", the objects are immutable, you don't need pure functions (since you use reactive programming), and I don't do that to "prove I can use rxjs", I do that because it is **clear, clean and concise**. If you can't begin to comprehend how RxJS works, then go away and flame in your corner of the room. No need to spit on those who actually try to help. By the way, the answer being marked as accepted, proves that it indeed helped. Seems like on your side, you didn't even try to. So go away.

Comment: @dagda1 if you use rxjs 5, you can avoid the pipe : `mySubject.map(...)` should work. Some operators may have changed too : [this page](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/) lists all the available operators, and their previous names if there is.

Comment: @trichetriche thank you, starting to not hate angular as much as long as you remove the magic.  OnPush should be the only way and reactive forms with rxjs give me the 1 way data flow I was after

Comment: @dagda1 I agree, the only thing missing is a default strategy so that the components always implement `onPush`. Right now, you have to do it manually on every component (or through the CLI with `-c`).

Comment: @dagda1 by the way, if you feel your issue is resolved, may I suggest you give the bounty away ?

Comment: I have accepted your answer, there is nothing more I can do.  I think you might have to wait a bit but I've done my bit.

Comment: I am an avid advocate of OnPush strategy usage for production level Angular projects. Just wanted to share a few articles that explain the concept, pitfalls and things to keep in mind when using OnPush. Hope it helps others get a hang of it. https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4 and https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/

Comment: @maryannah you CAN keep it TURNED ON by default. Go to your `angular.json` file > schematics > schematics/angular:component , and add "changeDetection": "OnPush" in it. Angular CLI should now generate components with OnPush by default. `ng g c new-push-test`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

According the template below and using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, `ChangeDetection` runs only after the button click. (It implements only to DOM events). Everything else won't affect and `DetectChanges()` function doesn't run (for example, the fetching some data from some resource won't affect on your code)

```js
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
   template: `
    <button (click)="uploadFiles()" [disabled]="!this.canUpload">Upload</button>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    uploadFiles() {
      .../*Here's function body*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitry S wrote in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54678285), we can set the ChangeDetectionStrategy of our component to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

This tells Angular that the component only depends on its `@inputs()` (aka pure), and needs to be checked only in the following cases:

1. The Input reference changes.
2. An event originated from the component or one of its children.
3. We run change detection explicitly.

Netanel Basal has published [a very helpful article on `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4).

Answer (score -1):

If you want full control over change detection, using the OnPush-Strategy, get a changeDetectorReference

```
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

and trigger change detection when you want to, e.g. when your array changes or in
your upload-method.

```
uploadFiles() { 
// ...
this.changeDetector.detectChanges()
}
```